# How to setup ESLint to format on each new line, in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, vscode-extensions, code-formatting

I'm trying to get ESLint to format with the `formatOnType` option. I know that the usual setup for the `settings.json` file is

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript"
    ],
}
```

Since VSCode has an inbuilt formatter that can run for each new line of code using the `formatOnType` option, I tried to configure the default formatter to be VSCode, in order to let this happen, I also enabled the format option for eslint.

```
{
    "editor.formatOnType": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript"
    ],
}
```

This way I can eliminate the `codeActionsOnSave` setting, since VSCode is supposed to run the formatter on its own. However the above setting doesn't work as is.
To cross-check, I changed the `formatOnType` option to `formatOnSave`

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
    "eslint.format.enable": true,
    "eslint.validate": [
        "javascript"
    ],
}
```

Now it works perfectly, but it defeats the entire purpose of me trying to set ESLint as the default formatter, which was to get it to run on each new line, as possible by the `formatOnType` option.

P.S. I already have the .eslintrc.json file setup with the Airbnb defaults

Comment: I'm pretty certain ESLint's Language Server for VS Code doesn't support `formatOnType`, or `formatOnPaste`, becuase ESLint, as far as I am aware, is not able to format specific blocks only, which it would need to be able to do, to build a language server that could support the configurations. Prettier also doesn't support the `formatOnType` & `formatOnPaste` configurations. The only formatter I used in the past that was able to do it was  CLang's Formatter for C++.

Comment: You could try creating an issue for it, but there are already a plethora of 'em.

Comment: @jD3V Rn I suspect that the issue surpasses ESLint and Prettier, and lies with VSCode. [This post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vscode/comments/772cw5/am_i_missing_something_about_editorformatontype/) talks about how a dev couldn't get it to work for a C++ formatter 
in VSCode either. Hopefully they fix it sometime in the future. What's the point of autosave, if you have to Ctrl+S anyway